# ActiveRecord: How to query multiple associations with an AND statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have product with multiple features, and features belong_to a feature_key and a feature_value.

Here is the query I'm running:

```
Product.family_features.joins(:feature_key, :feature_value)
       .where(feature_keys: { name: ["Color", "Size"] }, feature_values: { name: ["Red", "Large"] })
       .group_by(&:product_id)
```

**Note**: `.family_features` is a scope on Product that gets all the features related to the product's "family" -- which is a group of other products.

Now I want only one product that has a combination of features that have "color" => "red" and "size" => "large"

But I get features that have "color" => "red" and other sizes, as well as features with "size" => "large" and other colors.

Is there a way to constrain this query to the exact combination of values I need?

---

The relations look like this:

```
Product has_many :features

Feature belongs_to :product, :feature_key, :feature_value

FeatureKey has_many :features, :products (through features)
FeatureValue has_many :features, :products (through features)
```

Comment: The relations are not really obvious, so it would be nice if you could add the models you are using to your question.

Comment: The way I've gotten it to work is by combining the queries as a collection/map. Ex: `[{ key: "Color", value: "Red"}, { key: "Size", value: "Large"}].map { |f| Feature.joins...etc }.flatten.uniq.group_by(&:product_id)` -- but it's performs multiple queries that way, albeit the results are good. Is there anything more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using arel.

`fkt, fvt = FeatureKey.arel_table, FeatureValue.arel_table
color_red = fkt[:name].eq('Color').and(fvt[:name].eq('Red'))
size_large = fkt[:name].eq('Size').and(fvt[:name].eq('Large'))
Feature.joins(:feature_key, :feature_value)
       .where(color_red.or(size_large))
       .group(:product_id)`

I have not tested the code, but I think it should work.
Check the [arel documentation](https://github.com/rails/arel) for more details.

Note that I also changed the `group_by` to `group`. `group_by` is the `Enumerable` module Ruby method, while `group` is the ActiveRecord relation method performing an SQL `GROUP BY`, which should be much faster than grouping in Ruby.

Edit:
Though your comment is saying that it worked, if you need all products that have `size => large` and `color => red` combination, I do not think this was what you were looking for.

You could try something like this:

```
red_products = Product.joins(features: [:feature_key, :feature_value]).where({feature_keys: { name: 'color' }, feature_values: { name: 'red' }})
large_products = Product.joins(features: [:feature_key, :feature_value]).where({feature_keys: { name: 'size' }, feature_values: { name: 'large' }})
products = red_products & large_products
```

The issue with the above solution is that `&` is the array intersection in Ruby, therefore it will make two DB queries, and intersect the result in Ruby, which could become a problem for large datasets.

Comment: Wouldn't `.where(color_red.or(size_large))` need to be an `and` since I'm trying to get an exact match for both size and color combination?

Comment: Mm, looking at your models a feature only has a single key/value combination, which would make an `and` condition irrelevant in the above query. I suppose you want to get the products with these two feature is that right?

Comment: Correct. The `or` condition returns too much. The `and` doesn't return anything. The arel part of the query add the following statement, and while I'm not a SQL expert, it seems like the `AND`'s should be grouped by parentheses? `AND ("feature_keys"."name" = 'Color' AND "feature_values"."name" = 'Green' AND "feature_keys"."name" = 'Size' AND "feature_values"."name" = 'Large')`

Comment: Right, I actually messed up my original question. I am really looking for a single product that matches all those `features: [:feature_key, :feature_value]` combinations. The other problem is that the number of features per product that I'm looking to query is dynamic, so I can't use the `&` approach -- though I am iterating with a map, and I think it achieves a similar result.

Comment: One thing that does help is the products I'm interested in are only a "family" of related products... so I have their ids. Can't I take your original arel structure, build out the nested joins, and constrain the query to an `IN` clause for the product ids?